Where to find SHA256SUMS and SHA256.gpg?
Where can I get the SHA256SUMS and SHA256.gpg for Ubuntu 24.04-ISO? I can not find in ubuntu.com. It is so hard to find.

https://releases.ubuntu.com/noble/
